# whats wrong with my simple code

Tags: java

am trying to run this simple code but it still give me error ie system error on token','; expected at the line ; int blackbox.Area();

```
package box;
public class box {
    int height;
    int width;
    enter code here
    public int Area(){
        return height*width;    
    }

    box blackbox= new box();

public void main(){

     blackbox.height = 3;
     blackbox.width= 4;

  int blackbox.Area();

}
}
```

Comment: `int x= blackbox.Area();`

Comment: Your code won't work even after fixing the mentioned line. You'll run into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void main(){

     blackbox.height = 3;
     blackbox.width= 4;

  int val =  blackbox.Area(); // -> 5 line

}
```

your method is returning a value, so you may need another variable to catch it. The 5th line has syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tom. You need more specified way to solve the issue. You can make it done in various ways. As you are a beginner, you can do it in simple by making 2 classes.

**BoxAreaFinder.java**

```
public class BoxAreaFinder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box blackbox = new Box();
        blackbox.height = 3;
        blackbox.width = 4;
        int areaOfBlackBox = blackbox.Area();
        System.out.println(areaOfBlackBox);
    }
}
```

**Box.java**

```
public class Box {
    int height;
    int width;
    public int Area() {
        return height * width;
    }
}
```

**Output:**
12